# increase reading speed for python for read data from 7 sensors via comport

Tags: python

I have connected 7 devices by COM port (9600, 4800 baud rates) in my laptop, and I need to record data from all devices. I created a python script - to collect data via pandas in an excel table, but the speed is not good (I have 5 FPS, but I need 20 FPS). I tried to connect one sensor through the thread and pyperclip library, and it is a little better (FPS - 7), but still, the FPS is low. How else can you use it?
For good, do all data need to write data to the buffer via thread or not?[image]

Comment: Let's see the code. It's impossible to assure a better solution absent an existing solution.

Comment: What is your data acquisition rate for a single sensor without any disk interaction? Does the rate stay the same when communicating with them concurrently, e.g. via concurrent.futures? Is the disk interaction your bottle neck? If so, push that to a parallel thread as well.